# How to get data through google-news-api

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to create a console application in c# to get data (google news details) from google-news-api.
I was tried like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var _http = new HttpClient())
        {
            _http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://newsapi.org/v2/");
            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.GetAsync("everything?sources=&q=bbc-news&sortBy=publishedAt&pageSize=80&apiKey=4dbc17e007ab436fb66416009dfb59a8");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Ref:-[google news api](https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=4dbc17e007ab436fb66416009dfb59a8)

Comment: And what is your question? What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stacked in line no 8

Comment: Which line is line 8? And what exactly is your problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var _http = new HttpClient())
        {
            _http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://newsapi.org/v2/");
            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string response = MainAsync(_http).Result;

            //TODO: Handel the response string the way you wanted to 

        }
    }

    static  async Task<string> MainAsync(HttpClient _http)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response =  await _http.GetAsync("everything?sources=&q=bbc-news&sortBy=publishedAt&pageSize=80&apiKey=4dbc17e007ab436fb66416009dfb59a8");
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```